# Bounds on mixing strength of a quantum channel

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

Consider a quantum channel $E$ acting on a $d$ dimensional quantum state, with a Kraus representation $E(\rho)= \sum_{j=1}^{k}A_j\rho A^{\dagger}_j$ (where matrices $A_j$ satisfy $\sum_{j=1}^kA^{\dagger}_jA_j=I$).

Given a quantum state $\rho$, let $\lambda_{\text{max}}(\rho)$ be its largest eigenvalue. Now we can define a function on quantum channels as: $F(E)= \text{max}_{\rho}\lambda_{\text{max}}(E(\rho))$, where maximisation is over all quantum states.

$F(E)$ can be seen as a measure of strength of $E$ to output highly mixed states. If $F(E)$ is small, then even pure states get mapped to highly mixed states under action by $E$.

It is easy to give a lower bound of $\frac{1}{k}$ on $F(E)$, where $k$ is the number of operators in Kraus representation. But is it possible to give a stronger lower bound? Or a different lower bound which depends on both $k,d$ and is stronger than $\frac{1}{k}$ for some range of $d$?

Edit: Second question above has a simple answer of $\frac{1}{d}$ with $k>d$, as noted by @NorbertSchuch. So remaining question is the first one, a bound independent of $d$. It has been shown in http://arxiv.org/abs/0706.0556 that there is a quantum channel with $F(E)$ upper bounded by $\frac{2}{\sqrt{k}}$ as $d\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Yes. If $k>d$, then $1/d$ is a stronger lower bound.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: So to clarify: Do you want a better bound *purely* in terms of $k$ (i.e. independent of other properties of the channel)?

Comment: That is true. And if possible, example of a channel that achieves the bound.